# Proof involving subgraph of a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let $T$ be a tree with even number of vertices. Prove that $T$ has "exactly" one spanning subgraph in which all vertices have odd degree.

I could only think of this result:
In a tree with even number of vertices, the number of vertices with an odd number of children is odd.

But I don't know how to proceed. I'm self-studying discrete math and I found this question in a discrete math book.

EDIT:

The post linked in the comments proves existence of such tree. This question also requires the proof of uniqueness.

Comment: What do you mean by subgraph? Every tree has at least two leaves $u$ and $v$. If we take $u'$ and $v'$ which are adjacent to $u$ resp. to $v$ then we have two subgraphs with vertices of odd degree, namelay $G_1 =\{u,u'\}$ and $G_2 = \{v,v'\}$.

Comment: I imagine it is intended that the vertex set of the subgraph be the same as $T$, so vertices of degree zero would violate the condition.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Yup, the problem is missing 'spanning' in front of 'subgraph'. In that case, OP, I recommend induction.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question to include "spanning". @Matthew Daly

Comment: Sorry i edited the question to include "spanning" @Aqua

Comment: That proof only describes the existence of an all-odd spanning subgraph without talking about the uniqueness.  In the first two subcases, it's obvious that the solution is unique.  In the third, I think that you can convince yourself of it based on whether the number of leaves attached to $u$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick proof of uniqueness; the linked post already covers existence in multiple ways.

Let $G_1, G_2$ be two odd subgraphs of $T$. Then their symmetric difference $G_1 \mathbin{\Delta} G_2$ (which has every edge found in exactly one of $G_1$ or $G_2$) is an even subgraph of $T$: all vertices have even degree, possibly $0$.

Suppose that the even subgraph has any vertices of positive degree. Then start at one such vertex and take a walk, without repeating an edge, until you've returned to a vertex you've seen before. (You'll never get stuck, because no vertex of $G_1 \mathbin{\Delta} G_2$ has degree $1$. If you enter a vertex, you can leave it.)

But now we've found a cycle in $T$! This is impossible: trees don't have cycles. So $G_1 \mathbin{\Delta} G_2$ cannot have any vertices of positive degree - in other words, it's the empty graph. Therefore $G_1 = G_2$.